Карта залезает на футер
При просмотре страницы с моб. устройства, футер сужается, и уходит под карту. Помогите исправить, чтобы футер шел ровно после карты.


.contacts__map {
  position: revert;
  height: 300px;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.footer__grid {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer__col {
  max-width: revert;
  width: calc(50% - 1rem);
}

.footer__logo-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
<div id="map" class="contacts__map">
  <iframe src="https://yandex.ru/map-widget/v1/?um=constructor%3Ad223a6ea6ccaf95607ec3b3f9162efb0673547ebec54029c097eff3cdb2ca48a&amp;source=constructor" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</section>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer__grid">
      <div class="footer__logo-wrapper">
        <a href="index.html" class="footer__logo logo">Кровля-Сервис</a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer__services-wrapper footer__col">
        <h3 class="footer-heading">Услуги</h3>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="myagkaya-krovlya/index.html">Мягкая кровля</a></li>
            <li><a href="remont-kryshi-proizvodstvennyh-zdanij-skladov-angarov/index.html">Ремонт кровли ангаров и складов</a></li>
            <li><a href="naplavlyaemaya-krovlya/index.html">Ремонт наплавляемой кровли</a></li>
            <li><a href="montazh-falczevoj-krovli/index.html">Монтаж фальцевой кровли</a></li>
            <li><a href="ustranenie-protechki/index.html">Устранение протечек кровли</a></li>
            <li><a href="montazh-vodostochnoj-sistemy/index.html">Монтаж водосточной системы</a></li>
            <li><a href="ochistka-krovli-ot-snega-i-naledi/index.html">Очистка кровли от снега и наледи</a></li>
            <li><a href="obogrev-krovli-i-vodostokov/index.html">Обогрев кровли и водостоков</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="footer__contacts">
        <div class="footer__contacts__item">
          <div class="footer__contacts__label">Телефон</div>
          <div class="footer__contacts__value">
            <a href="tel:+79219230089">+7 921 923-00-89</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer__contacts__item">
          <div class="footer__contacts__label">Адрес</div>
          <div class="footer__contacts__value">
            г. Санкт-Петербург, пр-т Елизарова, д.38, литер А
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>



